# Serious issue with this CodeIgniter login script

Tags: php, codeigniter

People can login with even other users' passwords. I cannot figure what am I doing wrong.

```
function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|xss_clean|required|callback_login_user_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[4]|max_length[20]|callback_password_check|sha1');

    $this->_username = $this->input->post('username');
    $this->_password = $this->_salt.sha1($this->input->post('password'));


    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $toView['title']= 'Please login';
        $this->build_content($toView);
        $this->render_page();
    }
    else
    {

        $this->account_model->login();


        //$data['message'] = "You are logged in! Now go to ". anchor("members/dashboard","Dashboard");
        redirect('members/dashboard');

    }

}



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// password CHECKING

function password_check(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->_username);
    $this->db->where('password', $this->_password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->row_array();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check','There was an error! ');
        return FALSE;
    }

    if($result['password'] == $this->_password)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

}





function login_user_check($user)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username'=>$user));

    if(!$query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('login_user_check', 'The %s does not exists in our database');
        return FALSE;
    }

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            //$data[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $row['user_id']);
        }
    }

    $query->free_result();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you think is being accomplished when you call `where` 2 times in a row?

Comment: I am no expert, but does the two $this->db->where combine the clauses by OR or by AND?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#where) : `$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('title', $title);
$this->db->where('status', $status); 

// WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'` I can't come up with harder way to query a database to save my life :P

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling `where` twice - I'd personally pass in an array I.E. `$this->db->where(array('username' => $this->_username, 'password' => $this->_password))` - But both have the same outcome.

Comment: i think the script is checking any password or any user in the whole db and allows login if either of them are true, can anyone please help me to coorect this ? much appreceated

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query()` - See what SQL is actually being produced

Answer (score 0):

i tested the code - and it works for me. people can't login with other users' passwords. i don't know what your `account_model->login()` is doing, but to this point your script seems to be working just fine.

and you can replace (inside password_check() function)

```
    if($result['password'] == $this->_password)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

with

```
return TRUE;
```

(as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

```
function password_check(){

    // Check if one of values is empty, return false 
    if (empty($this->_username)||empty($this->_password))  return false;

    $this->db->where('username', $this->_username);
    $this->db->where('password', $this->_password);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For the case that the password is not equal your are not returning false. Try something like this:

```
function password_check(){
  $this->db->where('username', $this->_username);
  $this->db->where('password', $this->_password);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  $result = $query->row_array();

  if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
  {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check','There was an error! ');
      return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;

}
```

EDITED: return TRUE will suffice. See Comments.

Comment: Checking if the passwords are equal is redundant, since you're already querying based on the passwords matching. You can simply `return TRUE` at that point. The problem is something else.